# Filter RSS feeds to show today's content and sort by datetime descending

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, rss, filtering

I have a little script (found on the web) that collects RSS feed(s) into an array, sorts the array and then display how you want it. Now I would like to be able to only display the items from the feed from specific date (today only). Can anyone help filtering the sorted array?

```
   <?php
    //Feed URLs
    $feeds = array(
        "https://www.abda.de/?type=1102",
        "https://www.abda.de/?type=1100",
    );

    //Read each feed's items
    $entries = array();
    foreach($feeds as $feed) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
        $entries = array_merge($entries, $xml->xpath("//item"));
    }

    //Sort feed entries by pubDate

    usort($entries, function ($feed1, $feed2) {
        return strtotime($feed2->pubDate) - strtotime($feed1->pubDate);
    });

    function showrssitem($i) {
        global $entries;
        $backgroundbutton = 'd3d3d3';
        switch ($entries[$i]->category) {
            case "Chargenrückrufe" :
                $backgroundbutton = 'ff9933';       /* orange */
                break;
            case "Rückrufe" :
                $backgroundbutton = 'ff9933';       /* orange */
                break;
            case "Informationen der Institutionen und Behörden" : 
                $backgroundbutton = 'ff3300';       /* red */
                break;
            case "Informationen der Hersteller" : 
                $backgroundbutton = 'ff5500';       /* red 2 */
                break;
            case "AMK-PhaGro-Schnellinformationen" : 
                $backgroundbutton = 'ff7700';       /* red3  */
                break;
        }

        $strippedentry1 = str_replace ("Online-Nachricht: ","", $entries[$i]->title); 
        $strippedentry2 = str_replace ("Informationen der Institutionen und Behörden: ","", $strippedentry1); 
        $strippedentry3 = str_replace ("Informationen der Hersteller: ","", $strippedentry2); 
        echo '<a style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="' . $entries[$i]->link . '"><button style="background-color: #' . $backgroundbutton . '; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%; height:75px; display: block; border-radius: 10px;">' . $entries[$i]->category . '</button></a>';
        echo mb_strimwidth($strippedentry3,0,100,"...") . "<br>";
        echo "<i>[" . strftime('%d/%m/%Y', strtotime($entries[$i]->pubDate)) . "]</i><br>";

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Hi. Yes i tried array_filter to do the job but did not want to post code that does not work, sorry

Comment: This question would be easier to understand and answer if it had a [mcve].  Currently, contributors would need to make up their own sample data (and hope it is correct) or actually collect the feed data -- not ideal for a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me now. 
If you have any suggestions for a cleaner way, don't hesitate to comment ;)

```
   <?php
    //Feed URLs
    $feeds = array(
        "https://www.abda.de/?type=1102",
        "https://www.abda.de/?type=1100",
    );

    //Read each feed's items
    $entries = array();
    foreach($feeds as $feed) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
        $entries = array_merge($entries, ($xml->xpath("//item")));
    }

    //Sort feed entries by pubDate

    usort($entries, function ($feed1, $feed2) {
        return strtotime($feed2->pubDate) - strtotime($feed1->pubDate);
    });

    //Find latest date in array         $max = max(array_map('strtotime', $arr));
    $highestdate_entries = date('d-m-Y', max(array_map('strtotime', $entries)));    /* returns format 02-06-2020 */
    $entries_filtered = array_filter($entries, function ($var) use ($highestdate_entries) {

        return date('d-m-Y',(strtotime($var->pubDate))) === $highestdate_entries;       /* -> returns 1 */
    });

    //Reset the array so eg. id 10 moves to id 0
    $entries_filtered = array_values($entries_filtered);
    //Count the amount of items, so the for loop can be adjusted to that
    $numberofitems_entries = count($entries);
    $numberofitems_entries_filtered = count($entries_filtered);
    //echo "Items in entries : " . $numberofitems_entries . "<br>";
    //echo "Items in entries_filtered : " . $numberofitems_entries_filtered . "<br>" ;
    //echo "Latest date in entries : " . $highestdate_entries . "<br>" ;
    //echo strtotime($entries_filtered[0]->pubDate) . " === " . strtotime($dateoftoday);

    // XML feed provides 50 items per feed. Total is 100 items.

    // $dateoffeed=strftime("%d-%m-%y",strtotime($entries[0]->pubDate));
    // echo $dateoftoday;
    // Date format in xml feed:     Thu, 28 May 2020 12:17:38 +0200
    // Date format from date:       Mon, 01 Jun 2020 10:13:48 +0200
    // $dateoftoday=date(DATE_RFC2822);

    function showrssitem($i) {
        global $entries_filtered;
        $backgroundbutton = 'd3d3d3';
        switch ($entries_filtered[$i]->category) {
            case "Chargenrückrufe" :
                $backgroundbutton = 'ff9933';       /* orange */
                break;
            case "Rückrufe" :
                $backgroundbutton = 'ff9933';       /* orange */
                break;
            case "Informationen der Institutionen und Behörden" : 
                $backgroundbutton = 'ff3300';       /* red */
                break;
            case "Informationen der Hersteller" : 
                $backgroundbutton = 'ff5500';       /* red 2 */
                break;
            case "AMK-PhaGro-Schnellinformationen" : 
                $backgroundbutton = 'ff7700';       /* red3  */
                break;
        }

        $strippedentry1 = str_replace ("Online-Nachricht: ","", $entries_filtered[$i]->title); 
        $strippedentry2 = str_replace ("Informationen der Institutionen und Behörden: ","", $strippedentry1); 
        $strippedentry3 = str_replace ("Informationen der Hersteller: ","", $strippedentry2); 
        echo '<td style = "border=0px !important; width:20%"><a style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="' . $entries_filtered[$i]->link . '"><button style="background-color: #' . $backgroundbutton . '; margin-bottom: 0px; width: 100%; height:50px; display: block; border-radius: 10px;">' . $entries_filtered[$i]->category . '</button></a></td>';
        echo "<td><i>" . strftime('%d/%m/%Y', strtotime($entries_filtered[$i]->pubDate)) . ":</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo mb_strimwidth($strippedentry3,0,200,"...") . '</td>';
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: If `$entries` is an array of objects, then how can `array_map('strtotime', $entries)` work properly? `strtotime()` does not accept an object. https://3v4l.org/7005I

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the separation of data preparation and data presentation.

Do all of the filtering, sorting, and string manipulations in one place.

All of the following is untested code and may contain errors.

```
define(
    'CATEGORY_COLORS',
    [
        'Chargenrückrufe' => '#ff9933', // orange
        'Rückrufe' => '#ff9933', // orange
        'Informationen der Institutionen und Behörden' => '#ff3300', // red
        'Informationen der Hersteller' => '#ff5500', // red 2
        'AMK-PhaGro-Schnellinformationen' => '#ff7700', // red3
    ]
);

$feeds = [
    "https://www.example.com/?type=1102",
    "https://www.example.com/?type=1100",
];

$today = date('Y-m-d');
$datetimes = [];
$todaysEntries = [];
foreach ($feeds as $feed) {
    foreach (simplexml_load_file($feed)->xpath("//item") as $entry) {
        $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d F Y H:i:s O', $entry->pubDate); // Thu, 28 May 2020 12:17:38 +0200
        if ($dt->format('Y-m-d') === $today) {
            $datetimes[] = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $todaysEntries[] = (object) [
                'category' => $entry->category,
                'pubDate' => $dt->format('d/m/Y'),
                'link' => $entry->link,
                'color' => CATEGORY_COLORS[$entry->pubDate] ?? '#888888',
                'title' => str_replace(
                    [
                        'Online-Nachricht: ',
                        'Informationen der Institutionen und Behörden: ',
                        'Informationen der Hersteller: ',
                    ],
                    '',
                    $entry->title
                )
            ];
        }
    }
}

array_multisort($datetimes, SORT_DESC, $todaysEntries);
```

---

Then simply print your html rows.  (Try to move as much of your style declaration to an external stylesheet as much as possible.)

```
foreach ($todaysEntries as $entry) { 
    printf(
        '<tr>
            <td>
                <a target="_blank" href="%s">
                    <button style="background-color: %s;">%s</button>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <i>%s</i>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                %s
            </td>
        </tr>',
        $entry->link,
        $entry->color,
        $entry->category,
        $entry->pubDate,
        mb_strimwidth($entry->title, 0, 200, "...")
    );
}
```